# Locate unencrypted HTTP data with Wireshark

Tags: networking, encryption, ssl, wireshark

Part of an assignment for university is analysing packets from HTTP and HTTPS traffic, however Wireshark doesn't seem to be displaying the HTTP data as I would expecting - just to clarify, I am expecting to see the actual HTML code in one or more packets.

The only packets I see when attempting to load the page are in the image below.

[image: Image 1]

Looking into packet 32 shows some data, but not the actual HTML. It almost looks as though the HTML is encrypted, but I'm only using plain HTTP without SSL or TLS - is this the case? If so, why is it not in plain text?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it - I was looking at the correct packet, but the HTML code was compressed with GZIP.

To resolve this, I simply disabled mod_deflate on the server.

```
sudo a2dismod deflate
```

Now the HTML comes through as plain text!